# How do I disable Automatic Keyboard Correct Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I disable automatic correction when a user is typing in my application if they select an option? I'd like to do this by code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just add:

```
autoText="false"
```

If you are using an `AutoCompleteBox` you set

```
IsTextCompletionEnable = false;
```